# How we transfer 128bits cipher to a 4x4 matrix for AES input?

Tags: aes, encryption

Why the input cipher for AES encryption, can write in 4x4 matrix with 8 bits entires, and can said is 128bits? if each cell is 8bits in binary, how we said this matrix is represent 128bits?

Comment: A 4x4 matrix has 16 entries. Each entry is 8 bits. 16 times 8 bits is 128 bits. Anything unclear?

Comment: @fgrieu ya, great